# JavaScript array of dates and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am writing a function that takes an array of objects and parses the data into a date range. Right now I have the following:

```
function(result) {
  var dates = [];
  var data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    var story = result[i];

    var date = new Date(parseInt(story['UpdatedAt'].replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
    date.setHours(0);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    var estimate = story['Estimate'];
    if (estimate == null)
      estimate = 0;

    if (dates[date] == null) {
      dates[date] = [date, 1, estimate];
      data.push(dates[date]);
    } else {
      dates[date][1] += 1;
      dates[date][2] += estimate;
      data.push(dates[date]);
    }
  }

  console.log(dates);
  drawStoriesCompletedChart(data);
}
```

I have two arrays, one for dates and one for data. The result of this function is fed into the Google Charts API, which requires the data to be `[[a,b,c], [a,b,c]]`

The code above works thanks to the way Google Charts works, but I do know that since the data array is being pushed to every single loop iteration, there will be a bunch of duplicates without updated data.

What I want is take the data from each object and parse it so it is like the following:

`[[Date, Total Stories, Total Estimate], [...]]` and have nothing else in the object.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of the input you're working with and the output you want. A [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would be ideal.

Comment: If you know that dates are being duplicated due to pushing every single iteration of the loop then just don't push the dates array to the data array until your date processing is complete.

Comment: Note that your `dates` array will have values at indexes like 1498759748481, because you're using `dates[date]` and `date` is a Date value. The value of a Date object is the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970. That could very well be what's intended (I don't know anything about Google Charts), but just making sure.